# Sound class sounds layered and screechy on Windows

Tags: java, windows, audio, wav

So, when I'm on Mac, this error did not occur. However, when I am on Windows, any sounds I play multiple times over each other start sounding like they are becoming screechy and layering over each other in an unpleasant way.

Here is relevant code from my Sound class:

```
public class NewerSound {
    private boolean stop = true;
    private boolean loopable;
    private boolean isUrl;
    private URL fileUrl;
    private Thread sound;
    private double volume = 1.0;

    public NewerSound(URL url, boolean loopable) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
        isUrl = true;
        fileUrl = url;
        this.loopable = loopable;
    }

    public void play() {
        stop = false;
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                do {
                    try {
                        AudioInputStream in;
                        if(!isUrl)
                            in = getAudioInputStream(new File(fileName));
                        else
                            in = getAudioInputStream(fileUrl);
                        final AudioFormat outFormat = getOutFormat(in.getFormat());
                        final Info info = new Info(SourceDataLine.class, outFormat);
                        try(final SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info)) {
                            if(line != null) {
                                line.open(outFormat);
                                line.start();
                                AudioInputStream inputMystream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(outFormat, in);
                                stream(inputMystream, line);
                                line.drain();
                                line.stop();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException | IOException e) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                    }
                } while(loopable && !stop);
            }
        };
        sound = new Thread(r);
        sound.start();
    }

    private AudioFormat getOutFormat(AudioFormat inFormat) {
        final int ch = inFormat.getChannels();
        final float rate = inFormat.getSampleRate();
        return new AudioFormat(PCM_SIGNED, rate, 16, ch, ch * 2, rate, false);
    }

    private void stream(AudioInputStream in, SourceDataLine line) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
        for(int n = 0; n != -1 && !stop; n = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) {
            byte[] bufferTemp = new byte[buffer.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < bufferTemp.length; i += 2) {
                short audioSample = (short) ((short) ((buffer[i + 1] & 0xff) << 8) | (buffer[i] & 0xff));
                audioSample = (short) (audioSample * volume);
                bufferTemp[i] = (byte) audioSample;
                bufferTemp[i + 1] = (byte) (audioSample >> 8);
            }
            buffer = bufferTemp;
            line.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    }
}
```

It is possible that it could be an issue of accessing the same resources when playing the same sound multiple times over itself when I use the NewerSound.play() method.

Please let me know if any other details are needed. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using to change the volume in the method "stream" is flawed. you have 16-bit encoding, thus it takes two bytes to derive a single audio value. You need to assemble the value from the two byte pairs before the multiplication, then take apart the 16-bit result back into two bytes. There are a number of StackOverflow threads with code to do this.

I don't know if this is the whole reason for the problem you describe but it definitely could be, and definitely needs to be fixed.

Comment: The problem does not occur if I subtract out the multiplication of volume. Thanks for what you pointed out, though! I have modified my code to work with 16-bit audio above.